# Scrolling Problems in PhoneGap (jQuery Mobile) App

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have some strange scrolling problems with my PhoneGap (using jQuery Mobile) app:
I'm using a header and footer in my page. In between there is the content I want to display.
Because there is also a background image I'm using a container with white background color that the text in it is better readable. This container is positioned like this:

```
position:absolute; 
top: 77px; /*header height*/
bottom: 54px; /*footer height*/
left:10px; 
right:10px;
overflow: auto;
```

This works perfect when I test the page with FireFox, but it just does not work at the phone.
Anyone knows why?

edit: Sorry... it was tested with Android before, there is does not work. On iPhone it's working!

Comment: whats happening on the phone/

Comment: Nothing =)
It seems the container just hides the overflow...

Comment: I have tested it now with an iPhone... here it works as it should!

Is there something special on Android???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android in the version 1-3 interpret every overflow as overflow:hidden, so you cannot use overflow:scroll and have to use JavaScript-scrolling (http://www.androidannoyances.com/post/51)

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by using jQueryMobile's data-position=fixed or by using a 3rd party library like iScroll, which is what I used to solve the problem.